# Probability of a particular pattern

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting a 5,6 before 1 when you roll a dice sequentially ? Could some body use state diagram and law of total probability to solve this?

Comment: 5 or 6 before 1 is that what you mean?

Comment: 5, 6 means 5 immediately followed by 6